# How do you make a variable that is changing every reload?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, pageviews

The variable I'm talking about is like page views. I want it so the variable doesn't start at 1 every time. So every time you reload it, the pageviews variable adds by 1. All I have is:

HTML:

```
<div id='pageviews'></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var pageviews;
pageviews += 1;
document.getElementById('pageviews').innerHTML = pageviews;
```

I didn't use CSS because that was optional.

Comment: Store a count in localStorage.

Comment: @dystroy Not cookie ?

Comment: "didn't use CSS because that was optional"... wut ? Are you talking about a scholar exercice ? :) anyway : you want pages view by user, or for everyone ? If for user use cookie or localStorage. If "global" you nead a storage Server side : simple file or SQL for exemple.

Comment: If you want it to be incremented by several users, like a webpages' hit counter, it has to be incremented on the server, via a scripting language like PHP, and stored in a database.

Comment: if you want to avoid asking everytime you load a pageto your DB, check out COOKIES, i was doing this in my project and it works, check out this, i hope i helped you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `localStorage` to store the count as :

`var count = 0;`

`localStorage.setItem('count', count);`

and use `var count = localStorage.getItem('count');` to retrieve the value (remember localstorage stores as string and not as integer so you can't directly use it as an integer.

OR

Use Cookies, set a cookie by [setcookie()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.setcookie.php), although you will have to set some Expiry date to it.

EDIT : [This](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/js-session/index.html) is exactly what to want to achieve. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sessionStorage or localStorage deppending on the behaviour expected.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var currentUpdateCount = sessionStorage.getItem("updateCount") ? sessionStorage.getItem("updateCount") : 1;

        sessionStorage.setItem("updateCount", currentValues + 1);

    });
```

The sessionStorage is alive only in the time that the current session is open in the browser.

The localStorage persist after you close and open the browser again.

You can know more about the html5 storage system [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to send an ajax request to the server and store it in a database.

If you only want to test your code, you can use localStorage for now and then modify the code to send the ajax request later on.